# It is possible to make a cycle between the electric energy and the light-heat

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

A light bulb receives electrical energy, and this energy is not lost, but rather, it is transformed into light and caloric energy.

[image]

I was wondering, for a scientific fair project, if it is possible to perform a "cycle", so that the bulb receives electrical energy, which then transforms light and caloric and then, this light and caloric energy is re-obtained (recycled) and again to transform into electrical energy. Is this possible?, Apparently I am not creating new energy, only transforming it.

Comment: The problem with "caloric" energy (I would prefer the term "heat" or "thermal energy") is that you can't get more chaotic than that. Heat is just too messed to use it effectively; there will always be some losses, even fundamental ones, i.e. you cannot use an amount of heat to produce the same amount of heat. An this is a fundamental constraint, not an experimental one. For example, you could argue that the visible light emitted by the lamp could be picked up by 100% given an ideal reflector, but heat simply cannot be tamed.

Comment: Yes, you can by having the light shine on a photo voltaic panel. But the efficiency is much less than one, so whatever initial energy you put in the system is degraded to heat pretty quickly.

Comment: You can perform one or perhaps several cycles, but with each cycle you'll lose energy, so the process cannot continue for long. This falls under the second law of thermodynamics. One of its many versions states: "It is impossible to devise a cyclically operating device, the sole effect of which is to absorb energy in the form of heat from a single thermal reservoir and to deliver an equivalent amount of work".